# Issue with logging guild messages into console

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I tried this console.log command using discord.js.
It's suppose to send messages from my server to the terminal but it isnt working and its not showing any errors.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const Config = require("./data/config.json")
const intents = new Discord.Intents(32256)
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents })

client.on("ready", () => console.log("ready!"));

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    console.log(message.content);
});


client.login(Config.token)
```

Comment: What do the bitfield `32256` stand for ( name the intents please )

Comment: GUILD_MESSAGES (1 << 9)
GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS (1 << 10)
GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING (1 << 11)
DIRECT_MESSAGES (1 << 12)
DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS (1 << 13)
DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING (1 << 14)
contains these

Comment: Tag description for `visual-studio`: *Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem yesturday, and was caused by the Intents, i would suggest trying this out:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

If using the Intent Bits instead, it would be `32258` instead of `32256`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the bitfield `32256` contains GUILD_MESSAGES

Comment: @oehfbhshf Does the "ready" message fire?

Comment: @Jesper after using your method it doesn't fire but the 1 I use it does

Comment: @oehfbhshf Edited my answer. You need the GUILDS intent too, i just tested it